# Catch exceptions for executed sql in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have an SQL built dynamically and it has some corrupted strings in it like wrong column name or used *sm* instead of *sum*.

When I execute the `sparksession.sql()` on this generated string , the entire spark job fails as expected and I can see all the logs as in the resource manager logs.

Is there a way for me to catch this exception in a try catch block or so and handle this exception and move forward with my logic.

Answer (score 3):

For now this worked for me , but I dont think this is the ideal solution.

```
        try {
            return spark.sql(query);
        }catch (Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
}
```

This threw me a `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException` exception for all sql syntax , wrong column or tablename queries. But I couldnt catch this exception in particular though.